# ADF Copy Files and store meta data

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, filecopy

I'm new to ADF but know a few things about copying data from source to destination like files etc.

My requirement is to copy files from source to destination and while doing this activity , i
want to store the current file's metadata like (filename , filesize , extension) into cosmos db .

Is this possible ?
Needed some guidelines.

Comment: Yes, please use Copy Activity, add sink as CosmosDB. 
please read more about Copy Activity in MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview 
also, you can check the built-in examples in ADF, i think it will help you.

Comment: also, check in YouTube there are many examples of how to copy data in ADF

Comment: My source and destination will have to be azure file storage and file system respectively. 
By making sink as Cosmos DB , aren't we trying to make the destination as cosmos.

Comment: so why not making 2 activities one for file storage and one for cosmos db?